# How to change height of Owner-draw Listbox items whiling resizing Window?

Tags: winapi, listbox

I have Listbox with LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE style, and trying resize items height with WM_MEASUREITEM on WM_SIZE.

I wrote code next in WM_SIZE procedure, referred http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1401/Changing-Row-Height-in-an-owner-drawn-Control :

```
WINDOWPOS wp;
ZeroMemory (&wp, sizeof(WINDOWPOS));

wp.hwnd  = hwndListbox;
wp.cx    = iWidht;
wp.cy    = iHeight;
wp.flags = SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER;

// WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED for force generate WM_MEASUREITEM:
SendMessage (hwndListbox, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, 0, (LPARAM)&wp);
```

however, It dosen't work... (dosen't generate WM_MESUREITEM.)

Question: How to force generate WM_MESUREITEM, or Resizing of items height dynamically?

p.s I using C++ with Win32, not MFC.

Comment: Tough cookies, only clearing and re-adding the items looks good enough to get it to re-measure the items.  This is pretty high on the dont-do-that list.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you for the advice. Is it wrong way? but I have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`LB_SETITEMHEIGHT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message to change the height of listbox items.

Comment: thank you for answer! however, I tried LB_SETITEMHEIGHT before WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, it was some weired result. (re-paint problem, wrong scroll positions, etc...)